# Select specific days data for each month in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, masking

I have a dataframe with daily data, for over 3 years.
I would like to construct another dataframe containing the data from the last 5 days of each month.
The rows of the 'date' column would be in this case (for the new constructed dataframe) :

2013-01-27
2013-01-28
2013-01-29
2013-01-30
2013-01-31
2013-02-23
2013-02-25
2013-02-26
2013-02-27
2013-02-28

Could someone tell me how I could manage that ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to `dt.day` and `dt.days_in_month` with boolean indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2013-12-31',freq='D'),
                   'Value':np.random.rand(1461)})

df_out = df[df['Date'].dt.day > df['Date'].dt.days_in_month-5]

print(df_out.head(20))
```

Output:

```
          Date     Value
26  2010-01-27  0.097695
27  2010-01-28  0.236572
28  2010-01-29  0.910922
29  2010-01-30  0.777657
30  2010-01-31  0.943031
54  2010-02-24  0.217144
55  2010-02-25  0.970090
56  2010-02-26  0.658967
57  2010-02-27  0.189376
58  2010-02-28  0.229299
85  2010-03-27  0.986992
86  2010-03-28  0.980633
87  2010-03-29  0.258102
88  2010-03-30  0.827310
89  2010-03-31  0.813219
115 2010-04-26  0.135519
116 2010-04-27  0.263941
117 2010-04-28  0.120624
118 2010-04-29  0.993652
119 2010-04-30  0.901466
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column is named `Date`.

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month,df.Date.dt.year]).apply(lambda x: x[-5:]).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Date')
```